# vi - search the string you cursor is over?

Tags: search, vi

I looking more for a method that is "built-in" to `vi`, and not something that I could do in my `.vimrc`. Though, solutions for `.vimrc` are appreciated. :-)

When I want to search a string, sometimes that string is already typed in and I want to see if it's being used elsewhere on the document. For example: I see a variable, but I want to know where it was initialized, so I'll search that variable's name and keep clicking `n` or `SHIFT+n` til I find it.

```
int c = 0;
.
. //100s or 1000s of lines of code
.
c = 5;
```

Is there a shortcut way to search the string that my cursor is hovered over? Not the mouse cursor, but the vi cursor (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 5):

In **vim** just press * to search forward ... # will search backwards.

Oh: prepend * and # with g to also match partial words.

Comment: You've got it all mixed up. * for forward, # for backward, g*/g# for _not_ whole words. n/N to repeat search in the same/reverse direction.